# Logstash trigger exec not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using elk stack to log my server data, I have read in the documenation that logstash can be used to [trigger an alarm or event](https://primalcortex.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/logstash-how-to-trigger-an-alarm-or-event/) through the commnand *exec*

So I am trying to do the same, I would like to trigger a script when a  certain patter/string does appear in the log, so far my configuration looks like as below. However, it is not working and I cannot see if the script is executed or not. On the other hand, I am not sure whether the string is found or not, I have used the same string in Kibana and I can isolate the message in which I would like to trigger the alarm

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am running logstash within a docker, I mount the *nodeFail.bash* a volume using

```
volumes:
  - /root/t/nodeFail.bash:/tmp/logstash/nodeFail.bash
```

Thanks in advance,

```
$cat logstash.conf 
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
    gelf {
    }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }


    if "All brokers rejected" in [message]
    {
        exec {
            command => "/tmp/logstash/nodeFail.bash aNode 12345 start &"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the log?

Comment: Only that it has been started but anything more `{:timestamp=>"2016-10-10T12:59:10.872000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}
`

Comment: And are you sure that relevant documents are being matched for that output? Maybe you should add `stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }` right after the `exec` to see if relevant documents are being matched.

Comment: It does, adding that line I get the expected message that should trigger the exec, `"message" => "\e[90m DEBUG\e[0m All brokers rejected                     \e[90mDevAddr\e[0m=12345",
`

Comment: Are you sure that `/tmp/logstash/nodeFail.bash` is executable? did you `chmod a+x` it?

Comment: That's what I am trying to check now, but I am not able to find it out yet, since I run logstash in a docker containter

Comment: Are you mapping that executable script as a mounted volume?

Comment: Yes I do, I have updated the main post with how I define the volume